# Proof of The Third Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Here's what I'm trying to prove right now:

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Let $M$ be a linear subspace of $V$ and $N$ be a linear subspace of $M$. Prove that the mapping $x+N \mapsto x+M$ between the quotient spaces $V/N \to V/M$ is linear with kernel $M/N$. Then, deduce that:

$$\frac{V/N}{M/N} \cong V/M$$

---

Proof Attempt:

We have to show that the given relation $T: V/N \to V/M$ is a linear mapping. We define:

$$\forall x \in V: T(x+N) = x+M$$

This is totally-defined. To show well-definedness, let $x+N = y+N$ where $x,y \in V$. Then, $x-y \in N$. So, $x-y \in M$. Hence:

$$x + M = y+M$$

$$\iff T(x+N) = T(y+N)$$

To prove that it is linear, we need to show additivity and homogeneity.

1. Proof of Additivity

Let $u,v \in V/N$. Then, $u = x+N$ and $v = y+N$ for some $x,y \in V$. Then:

$$T(u+v) = T((x+N)+(y+N)) = T((x+y)+N) = (x+y)+M = (x+M)+(y+M) = T(u) + T(v)$$

This proves additivity.

2. Proof of Homogeneity

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ and $u \in V/N$. Then, $u = x+N$ for some $x \in V$. So:

$$T(\alpha u) = T(\alpha(x+N)) = T(\alpha x +N) = \alpha x + M = \alpha (x+M) = \alpha T(u)$$

This proves homogeneity. Hence, $T$ is a linear map. To show that the kernel of $T$ is $M/N$, we have:

$$T(x+N) = x+M = \theta_V+M$$

$$\iff x \in M$$

$$\iff x+N \in M/N$$

$$\iff \ker(T) = M/N$$

Now, we notice that $T$ is surjective. By the first isomorphism theorem, it follows that:

$$\frac{V/N}{M/N} \cong V/M$$

That proves the desired result.

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, why? How can I fix it?

Comment: I think this is your third question about isomorphism problems. Hope it is the last.

Comment: I certainly hope it's the last. I'm starting to get a little more intuition about quotient spaces so hopefully, I don't have any other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is absolutely right!

I would change the part concerning $\ker T$, writing:
\begin{align}
x + N \in \ker T & \iff T(x+N) = 0 \in V/M \\
 & \iff x+M = 0 \in V/M \\
 & \iff x \in M \\
 & \iff x + N \in M/N
\end{align}
which means $\ker T = M/N$.

Comment: Ohh that makes more sense. Thank you so much, will accept your answer when it lets me do so. (Hopefully there are no more isomorphism theorems to prove after this one lol)